# How to convert struct/class instances to json string in c++11?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, struct, deserialization

I want to convert struct or class instances to JSON string in C++11. Now I'm using [picojson](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) to create a JSON string from struct data. However, I have a lot of types of struct so it's a really tough task because I have to catch up the struct specification and also have to modify my code which generates a JSON string manually.

I have to do this task in a C++11 environment, so I can't use [ThorsSerializer](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSerializer/blob/master/doc/example1.md). Are there any solutions? Java could actually do this by Jackson library and property annotations.

Comment: Have you checked out Boost Spirit ? I think it does that maybe with some additional work.

Comment: [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) is good if you c++11 compiler.

Comment: since picojson is header-only I would stick with that. ThorsSerializer pulls in all kinds of horrid dependencies. what you're looking for is an easy way to iterate through members and name them. should be simple enough with a few templates.